# Find b to make the three numbers in AP

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

For a positive number '$b$', the value of '$b$' for which the numbers $3^x + 3^{-x} , b ,9^x+ 9^{-x}$ are in A.P. can be : (A) 1 (B) 2 (C) 3 (D) 5​

Hello! This question has multiple correct answers and belongs to the topic Arithmetic Progression(Sequence and series). I was able to get the answer b=2. As we know that any number of the form $y + y^{-1}$ can take all values in the set = $(- ∞,-2]∪[2,∞)$. By taking $3^x + 3^{-x} = 2$, I got a constant AP = $2,2,2$. The answers are option (B),(C) and (D). Please help me reach the full solution.

Comment: Is it $9-x$ or $9^{-x}$?

Comment: so sorry. it's 9^-x

Comment: No worries, I edited it

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to stackexchange so i am just learning.

Comment: You don't actually need to find $b$ you just need to prove that $3^x+3^{-x}+9^{x}+9^{-x}=2b$ is possible, for $b=1$ it's clearly impossible since the expression is bigger than $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{3^x+3^{-x}+9^x + 9^{-x}}{2} &= \frac{3^x+3^{-x}+(3^x+3^{-x})^2-2}{2}\\
&= -1 + \frac{(3^x+3^{-x})+(3^x+3^{-x})^2}{2}
\end{align}

We know that the range of $3^{x}+3^{-x}$ is $[2, \infty)$

Hence the range of $(3^x+3^{-x})+(3^x+3^{-x})^2$ is  $[6, \infty)$.

Hence $b$ can attain any number at least $\frac{6}{2}-1=2$.

Comment: Thank you so much.