# If $x\in\mathbb R$ and $(5^{1+x}+5^{1-x}),\frac{a}{2},(25^x+25^{-x})$ are in $AP$ then $a$ lies in interval of?

Tags: sequences-and-series, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, arithmetic-progressions

> $Q.$ If $x\in\mathbb R$ and $(5^{1+x}+5^{1-x}),\frac{a}{2},(25^x+25^{-x})$ are in $AP$ then $a$ lies in interval of $?$

*Attempt 1 :* lets say that its an increasing AP then, $$5^{1+x}+5^{1-x}<\frac{a}{2}<25^x+25^{-x}$$

Mininmum value of $5^{1+x}+5^{1-x} $ & $ 25^x+25^{-x}$ will be (by AM-GM) , $10$ and $2$ .

and $$2<\frac{a}{2}<10$$

Hence interval of $a$ will be $[12,\infty)$

**Attempt 2 :** if $x,y,z$ are in AP then $$x+z=2y$$
By that $$a=5^{1+x}+5^{1-x}+25^x+25^{-x}$$

By AM-GM I can say $$\frac{5^{1+x}+5^{1-x}+25^x+25^{-x}}{4}>\sqrt[4]{5^{1+x}\times5^{1-x}\times25^x\times25^{-x}}$$ OR $$a>4\sqrt[4]{25}$$

**Doubt :** in my second attempt , why I didn't my answer matched the answer from first attempt .

Is there another way of solving this ?

Comment: Issue with 1) Just because the minimum of LHS and RHS is 2 and 10, doesn't mean that we can guarantee $a=12$ to occur. IE That happens iff equality occurs for the same $x$ value (which I haven't checked if it does).  $\quad $ Issue with 2) Can equality hold in your AM-GM? If not, it's not that tight, and so you've found a superset of possibilities, but need to tighten it further.

Comment: @CalvinLin So , how can I tighten it further ? can you give a hint ?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155706/find-b-to-make-the-three-numbers-in-ap?noredirect=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is essentially to find the range of $ 25^x + 5^{1+x} + 5 ^ { 1 - x } + 25^{-x}$ subject to $ x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Using the substitution $ 5^x = y$, we want to find the range of $ y^2 + 5y + \frac{5}{y} + \frac{ 1}{y^2} $, subject to $ y  > 0$.

Applying AM-GM creatively (and I'm leaving this step to you), show that the minimum occurs at

> $y=1$ and has value $12$.

Hence $ a \in \ldots $.

---

Note: With reference to my comment, as it turns out equality happens for the same $x$ value for the LHS and RHS.